# How to iterate through all properties in a ViewModel

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a lot of repeated code in my asp.net MVC views

```
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MyProperty)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.MyProperty)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MyProperty)
    </div>
```

I want to wrap this in something like:

```
foreach (System.Reflection.PropertyInfo item in Model.GetType().GetProperties())
```

and reuse the same partial view throughout.  But I can't get the syntax quite right.

How can I make this more generic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what Display and EditorTemplates are for.

You need only do `@Html.EditorForModel()` and then define a generic template for your model.